# Telegram-бот не реагирует на команды

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Создал `telegram`-бота. При запуске никаких ошибок не возникает.

Но, когда нажимаю на любую команду, ничего не происходит.
Можете подсказать, в чём возможна ошибка?

Часть кода:

```py
class TelegramBot():
    def __init__(self):

        self.Numberphone = ""
        self.family_name = ""
        self.name = ""
        self.given_name = ""
        self.distributor_id = ""
        self.userID = ""
        self.lastname = ""
        self.firstname = ""
        self.newphone = ""

        self.orders = []

        self.AllSumaDebts = []
        self.AllOverdueDebts = []


        self.ordersname = []
        self.ID = ''

        self.name = ''

        self.text = ''
        self.end_string = ''
        self.one = ''
        self.IDsroutes = []
        self.Namereponsibleroutes = []
        self.ListNamereponsibleroutes = []
        self.ListIDresponsibleroutes = []
        self.IDresponsibs = []
        self.Nameresponsibs = ''
        self.alltext = []
        self.today = ""
        self.datainjson = ""
        self.answearIDforTask = ""
        self.alltext3 = ""
        self.alltext4 = ""
        self.data = ""
        self.sumaI1 = 0
        self.sumaI2 = 0
        self.datas = {}


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def send_welcome(message):

        db = Client.TelegramUsers

        coll = db.Users
        ID_user = message.from_user.id
        print(ID_user)

        searchdata = {"telegram_contact.phone_number": ID_user}

        search = coll.find_one(searchdata)
        print(search)
        for key in TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser:
            TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser['distributor_id'] = ""
            TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser['given_name'] = ""
            TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser['family_name'] = ""
            TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser['middle_name'] = ""
            TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser['name'] = ""
            TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser['id'] = ""
            TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser['telegram_contact']['phone_number'] = ""
            TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser['telegram_contact']['first_name'] = ""
            TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser['telegram_contact']['last_name'] = ""
            TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser['telegram_contact']['user_id'] = ""

        pprint(TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser)

        keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
        contact = telebot.types.KeyboardButton("Отправить контакт", request_contact=True)
        keyboard.add(contact)

        TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser['telegram_contact']['user_id'] = message.from_user.id

        TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser['telegram_contact']['last_name'] = message.from_user.last_name
        TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser['telegram_contact']['first_name'] = message.from_user.first_name
        TelegramBot.firstname = message.from_user.first_name
        pprint(TelegramBot.InfoAboutUser)
        bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отправте свой контакт", reply_markup=keyboard)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, contact_handler)
```

Comment: Что у вас в консоли после запуска скрипта?
У вас процесс запускает или отрабатывает и останавливается?

Comment: Вы используете bot.polling() ?

Comment: @Alexsey Kr В консоле нечего не отображаеться. Да, я использую polling